# NULL fields during import CSV to Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, csv, import

I have to import a CSV file in a table of MySql db using a PHP script.
The CSV file is the following:

```
"giorno","lmedollton","changedolleuro","euroton","lmesterton","delnotiz","girm","sgm"
"2016-09-02", "100.01", "4005.09", "5000", "1.09", "120.09", "100.5", "200.77"
"2016-09-03", "150.01", "4205.09", "5600", "1.10", "150.09", "300.5", "300.77"
```

The table structure is the following:

```
#   Campo   Tipo    Collation   Attributi   Null    
    1   id  int(20)         No  Nessuno AUTO_INCREMENT   
    2   giorno  date            Sì  NULL    
    3   lmedollton  float           Sì  NULL         
    4   changedolleuro  float           Sì  NULL         
    5   euroton float           Sì  NULL         
    6   lmesterton  float           Sì  NULL         
    7   delnotiz    float           Sì  NULL          
    8   girm    float           Sì  NULL         
    9   sgm float           Sì  NULL
```

There are two many problems:

1) Using this PHP code:

```
    $csvFile = "../scripts/tabella.csv";

        $db = @mysql_connect('***', '***', '***');
        @mysql_select_db('***');

        $query = 'LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE \' '. $csvFile .' \' INTO TABLE rame FIELDS TERMINATED BY \',\' ENCLOSED BY \'"\' LINES TERMINATED BY \'\n\' 
(giorno,lmedollton,changedolleuro,euroton,lmesterton,delnotiz,girm,sgm)';

        if(!mysql_query($query)){
            die(mysql_error());
        }
        //@mysql_query($query);

        mysql_close($db);
```

mysql_error returns 'file not found'; I tried to use the realpath function also but the error is the same. The CSV file is in the site server in www.valuebiz.it/valuebiz/scripts/tabella.csv and its permissions are 777. Using this path like a URL I can download tabella.csv correctly.
Which is the correct path that I've to use?

2) I tried to work the query in my localhost and it runs but every fields of the added records are NULL. The table has 9 fields include id field (auto-increment): the first is a DATE type and others are FLOAT type. 
Why are inserted values NULL?

Can you help me, please?
Thanks!

Comment: no csv file in this location  : www.valuebiz.it/valuebiz/scripts/tabella.csv try to open file manually with this path.

Comment: You need to give a path in the _filesystem_, not a URL.  Save that file on the server to some location, go with that.

Comment: @Dave, I try it and the path is correct and the file is downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

I see three major problems with your import attempt.  First, if the file path is wrong, nothing is going to move.  Second, you should be using `IGNORE 1 LINES` at the end of the command to tell MySQL that your CSV file has a one line header at the beginning.  Third, I think you should be using `LOAD DATA INFILE`, not `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE`, as you are executing this code from the server, not the client.  Try something along these lines:

**Windows:**

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:/path/to/data.csv' INTO TABLE rame
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
(giorno, lmedollton, changedolleuro, euroton, lmesterton, delnotiz, girm, sgm);
```

**Unix:**

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '\path\to\data.csv' INTO TABLE rame
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
(giorno, lmedollton, changedolleuro, euroton, lmesterton, delnotiz, girm, sgm);
```

Comment: Thanks, the path is wrong but I don't know why. In Fileziila folders structure it's in www.site.it/site/scripts/tabella.csv. Why it didn't found? I tried this query in my localhost (windows machine) and the result is always NULL value for every fields

Comment: Are you using Linux or Windows?  Update your question with the table definition for the `rame` table.

Comment: Did you actually try my answer yet?

Comment: Can you echo the CSV file to the console from your PHP script?  This way, at least we would know that the file you are referencing exists/is reachable at that path.

Comment: Printing $csvFile content (using file_get_contents function) I obtain: string(188) ""2016-09-02, ""100.01"", ""4005.09"", ""5000"", ""1.09"", ""120.09"", ""100.5"", ""200.77""" "2016-09-03, ""150.01"", ""4205.09"", ""5600"", ""1.10"", ""150.09"", ""300.5"", ""300.77""" "